# convert hex to ascii characters xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am wondering what the logic for converting hex to ascii characters in XSLT 1.0 is like.
I need to convert `496e7465726e616c204d65646963696e65` to `Internal Medicine` using XSLT 1.0 template.

I have a template to convert ascii to hex and just need help to reverse the logic. Can some XSLT gurus help me with the logic?

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- the next line is all on one line and the before the ! is a space -->
  <xsl:variable name="ascii"> !"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="hex" >0123456789ABCDEF</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="foo" select="'I have $1,001.'"/>

    <result>
      <string>
        <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
      </string>
      <hex>
        <xsl:call-template name="recurse-over-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$foo"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </hex>
    </result>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="recurse-over-string">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>   
    <xsl:if test="$str">
      <xsl:variable name="first-char" select="substring($str,1,1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ascii-value" select="string-length(substring-before($ascii,$first-char)) + 32"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hex-digit1" select="substring($hex,floor($ascii-value div 16) + 1,1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hex-digit2" select="substring($hex,$ascii-value mod 16 + 1,1)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($hex-digit1,$hex-digit2)"/>
      <xsl:if test="string-length($str) &gt; 1">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="recurse-over-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,2)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? Seems pretty straightforward. -- Also, are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes limited to XSLT version 1. I am not sure if I can reuse the substing logic to convert hex to character? I am guessing I need to change the div and mod? The above code converts ascii to hex, i want the opposite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rather trivial exercise in base conversion:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="str">496e7465726e616c204d65646963696e65</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="hex">0123456789abcdef</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ascii"> !"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <acii>
        <xsl:call-template name="hex-to-ascii">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$str"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </acii>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="hex-to-ascii">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>   
    <xsl:if test="$str">
        <!-- extract first 2 digits -->
        <xsl:variable name="char1" select="substring($str, 1, 1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="char2" select="substring($str, 2, 1)"/>
        <!-- get their hex values -->
        <xsl:variable name="val1" select="string-length(substring-before($hex, $char1))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="val2" select="string-length(substring-before($hex, $char2))"/>
        <!-- convert to dec value -->
        <xsl:variable name="dec-value" select="$val1 * 16 + $val2"/>
        <!-- get the corresponding ascii character -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($ascii, $dec-value - 31, 1)"/>
        <!-- recursive call with the rest of the hex string -->
        <xsl:call-template name="hex-to-ascii">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str, 3)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<acii>Internal Medicine</acii>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem in **XSLT 2.0** and couldn't find a similar question for this version. I'd like to share a solution that's adapted from an idea provided by [michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k). A noteworthy difference is that **XSLT 2.0** introduced a new method, [codepoints-to-string](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-codepoints-to-string), which can streamline the solution: 

**XSLT 2.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:local="https://www.local.org"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="str">49 6E 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 20 4D 65 64 69 63 69 6E 65</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="hex">0123456789ABCDEF</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="local:hex-to-ascii($str)" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:function name="local:hex-to-ascii">
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tail" select="translate($str, ' ', '')" />
        <xsl:if test="$tail">
            <!-- extract first 2 digits -->
            <xsl:variable name="char1" select="substring($tail, 1, 1)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="char2" select="substring($tail, 2, 1)"/>
            <!-- get their hex values -->
            <xsl:variable name="val1" select="string-length(substring-before($hex, $char1))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="val2" select="string-length(substring-before($hex, $char2))"/>
            <!-- get the corresponding ascii character -->
            <xsl:variable name ="head" select="codepoints-to-string($val1 * 16 + $val2)"/>
            <!-- recursive call with the rest of the hex string -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($head, local:hex-to-ascii(substring($tail, 3)))" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note:

- This solution is tailored for **XSLT 2.0**.
- With this approach, we use entire **ASCII** charset.
- This solution also handles spaces between characters if they are exist.
- For clarity, I used an `xsl:function` instead of `xsl:template`, though the underlying logic remains the same.

Comment: If your input is delimited by spaces, you could tokenize it and eliminate the need for recursion. BTW, a two-char hex code can only go up 255, so you're still limited to (extended) ASCII.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for the comment. You are right. I updated the answer according to ascii charset. As for `tokenize` - you are right too, though I decided to leave code as is in case if somebody won't have spaces between characters.

Comment: Even if they do not have spaces, they can still construct a sequence of character pairs using an expression like `for $i in 1 to string-length($input) div 2 return substring($input, 2*($i - 1) + 1, 2))`.

Comment: Or even using `xsl:analyze-string`. That would probably be the best way, since you can also separate the pair's characters at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might approach this in **XSLT 2.0** or **XSLT 3.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="input">496e7465726e616c204d65646963696e65</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ascii>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:hex-to-ascii($input)" />
    </ascii>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="my:hex-to-ascii">
    <xsl:param name="hex-string"/>
    <!-- divide input string into pairs of hex characters + normalize to upper-case -->
    <xsl:analyze-string select="upper-case($hex-string)" regex="(.)(.)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <!--  convert each character of the pair to decimal value -->
            <xsl:variable name="dec-values" select="for $char in (regex-group(1), regex-group(2)) return if (matches($char, '[A-F]')) then 10 + xs:integer(translate($char, 'ABCDEF', '012345')) else xs:integer($char)"/>
            <!--  output the corresponding ASCII character -->  
            <xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string($dec-values[1] * 16 + $dec-values[2])" />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For XSLT 3.0, I considered using a [map](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#maps-and-arrays) to convert a hex character to the corresponding decimal value, but in the end it resulted in more code instead of less.